# Transfer to gnosis safe through contract failing due to out of gas errors

Tags: out-of-gas, gnosis-safe

We have a contract deployed on the mainnet at [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1d69a5cee83381459a2589828df5e8d82ca2cb88) address, we are trying to withdraw the ETH from it to a gnosis safe at [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0xE776DF26ac31C46a302F495c61b1fab1198C582a#code) address which is failing due to out-of-gas exceptions [tx1](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x35cb89cf67a025c415badf40ff166fd817d8d29d23569dbc87f8ff59fec0345f).

We tried using [this](https://github.com/folia-app/eip-2929) repo which is made for this reason specifically which did not work (possibly due to us using it wrongly?) here's 2 txs made with access lists.
[tx2](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x583826a40625c8b6da5d4b097a4a91e06aa75333b36bcc58ec1177985a008ae2) [tx3](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x00b821984e14972e41466db971275fe20c8200038d34293bab740a8e809652d9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, we did it! We were using wrong access lists, this is the successful [TX](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xad07c974c9235ac6078a2153cf90b826a52555c7fb5100400bf0cec1699ed0ad)

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem, which access list and node provider (Infura?) have you used? What addresses to put inside access list? Oh, and what to put in storageKeys? Thx in advance!

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123750/how-to-implement-eip-2930-access-list