# How to implement EIP-2930 access list?

Tags: gnosis-safe

**Update**

So yeah you do have to use https://github.com/folia-app/eip-2929 implementation, but what to put in the access list ?

All addresses involved in the Tx + the Gnosis safe Singleton address (known at safe creation).

In my case:

1. The address with which I am calling the SC method (`owner`)
2. The Gnosis safe public address
3. The Gnosis safe singleton address

As per the `storageKeys` I did put `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` for 1. and 2. Not too sure why.

```js
const tx = await contract.connect(signer).withdraw({
  gasLimit: 50_000,
  type: 1,
  accessList: [
    {
      address: "0x0000_OWNER_ADDRESS",
      storageKeys: [
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      ],
    },
    {
      address: "0x0000_SAFE_ADDRESS",
      storageKeys: [
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      ],
    },
    {
      address: "0x0000_SAFE_SINGLETON_ADDRESS",
      storageKeys: [],
    },
  ],
});
```

*Note*: Do not forget `type: 1`.

Uf. That was stressful.

Hope this helps !

**Original**

I cannot withdraw from contract to gnosis safe because of Berlin upgrade EIP-2929.

In a nutshell it seems like contract to contract internal Tx cannot spend more that 2300 gas anymore.

Which is incompatible with Gnosis safe contracts:
https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe

But as highlighted in article, there seem to be a way around this shortcoming using EIP-2930 access list.

I need help to implement a solution (ethers.js). I don’t know which addresses to “whitelist” and what are storage keys? Or even which node provider to use? Does Infura or Alchemix support EIP-2930? Etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example with gnosis safe and ethers.js here: https://github.com/folia-app/eip-2929/blob/master/index.js

You need to include two items in the access list:

1. Your Gnosis Safe proxy address with storage slot 0, where the address of the implementation contract is stored
2. Gnosis Safe implementation contract address

Comment: Hey, thanks I figured it out. You have to include as well the address calling the smart contract method !

Comment: What does "with storage slot 0" mean here?

Comment: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/internals/layout_in_storage.html

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, not enough reputation to comment) Can someone please tell me the difference between the "safe address" and the "safe singleton address"?