# Funds in smart-contract won't withdraw to Gnosis Safe Address

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I have a simple NFT smart contract that withdraws funds to multiple addresses including one Safe address. However, the execution reverts.

I've duplicated the contract on goerli testnet:

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x57468D4b4f45950898b65a8E3Dc3B7DAdA9d72B9

Also, I've created a goerli safe:

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xf13B6e39203186ce04E35434FE701F83C6353191

Here's the code snippet that handles the withdrawal:

```
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner nonReentrant {
    
    uint256 balance = address(this).balance;

    bool success;
    (success, ) = payable(0xf13B6e39203186ce04E35434FE701F83C6353191).call{value: ((balance * 35) / 100)}("Dao");
    require(success, "Dao Transaction Unsuccessful");
```

Here's one execution of the withdrawal:

https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x0ea40311cb1de1cd14961c9b76f33437143dd282d1df49131d28cb36662745f2

I've tried multiple solutions like transferring ownership to the Safe and then executing the withdrawal from within the safe. That results in GS103 error.

Comment: I seem to think it's something to do with a lack of multisignature.. let me have a dig

Comment: I've explored the issue in detail and it seems its similar to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123750/how-to-implement-eip-2930-access-list

However, the method didnt work. I created a simpler contract: `0x1a2e2ED504BdE006c724f9ff90fa1b03A74e6Bec`

and a new safe: `0x228Dd1F90A492F7278EDE4DEd63C02a3d2Db664E`

Here's the code snippet I've copied from the similar issue: https://ibb.co/8P62TsW

Comment: Please verify contracts on etherscan when submitting them to people for debugging

Comment: As a shot in the dark, try not to pass any transaction data to the call.

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade the gnosis contract? Cuz my contract is live and already holds funds.